# Improving speed of Matlab script in Labview

Tags: performance, matlab, labview

I have an issue with a Matlab script running in Labview: it takes 0.5 seconds to run on Matlab and over 10 seconds if called from Labview. I know it's supposed to be slower but well... Could someone have a look at my code to see if there's a way to improve it? I dread writing it in pure Labview...

```
clearvars
Size0=1024;
Size1=1280;
r=1;
g=1;
b=1;
RedArray=ones(Size0,Size1);
GreenArray=2*RedArray;
BlueArray=3*RedArray;
G1(Size0,:)=GreenArray(Size0,:);
G2(Size0,:)=GreenArray(Size0,:);
G1(1,:)=GreenArray(1,:);
G2(1,:)=GreenArray(1,:);
G1(:,Size1)=GreenArray(:,Size1);
G2(:,Size1)=GreenArray(:,Size1);
G1(:,1)=GreenArray(:,1);
G2(:,1)=GreenArray(:,1);

for(i=2:Size0-1)
  for(j=2:Size1-1)
    if(abs(GreenArray(i-1,j)-GreenArray(i+1,j))<abs(GreenArray(i,j-1)-GreenArray(i,j+1)))
        G1(i,j)=(GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i-1,j))/2;
        G2(i,j)=(GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i+1,j))/2;
    elseif(abs(GreenArray(i-1,j)-GreenArray(i+1,j))>abs(GreenArray(i,j-1)-GreenArray(i,j+1)))
        G1(i,j)=(GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i,j+1))/2;
        G2(i,j)=(GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i,j-1))/2;
    else
        G1(i,j)=(2*GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i,j+1)+GreenArray(i-1,j))/4;
        G2(i,j)=(2*GreenArray(i,j)+GreenArray(i,j-1)+GreenArray(i+1,j))/4;
    end
  end
end
U=zeros(2*Size0,2*Size1);
U(1:2:2*Size0,1:2:2*Size1)=r*RedArray;
U(2:2:2*Size0,2:2:2*Size1)=b*BlueArray;
U(2:2:2*Size0,1:2:2*Size1)=g*G1;
U(1:2:2*Size0,2:2:2*Size1)=g*G2;
```

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you calling the MATLAB code from LabVIEW? Is it actually running in MATLAB, or in NI's Mathscript?

Comment: Also FWIW: I'm no MATLAB expert but it looks as if that code would be pretty trivial to implement in LabVIEW...

Comment: vectorize loops get rid of if statements then compile to a lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try vectorizing those loops.   Loops are usually a performance killer, so if you try and vectorize the loops, you may get a performance boost in LabVIEW.

The loop code can be replaced with:

```
[I,J] = ndgrid(2:Size0-1,2:Size1-1);
ind1 = sub2ind([Size0, Size1], I-1, J);
ind2 = sub2ind([Size0, Size1], I+1, J);
ind3 = sub2ind([Size0, Size1], I, J-1);
ind4 = sub2ind([Size0, Size1], I, J+1);

g0 = GreenArray;
g1 = GreenArray(ind1);
g2 = GreenArray(ind2);
g3 = GreenArray(ind3);
g4 = GreenArray(ind4);

b1 = abs(g1 - g2) < abs(g3 - g4);
G1(b1) = (g0(b1) + g1(b1)) / 2;
G2(b1) = (g0(b1) + g2(b1)) / 2;

b2 = abs(g1 - g2) > abs(g3 - g4);
G1(b2) = (g0(b2) + g4(b2)) / 2;
G2(b2) = (g0(b2) + g3(b2)) / 2;

b3 = abs(g1 - g2) == abs(g3 - g4);
G1(b3) = (2*g0(b3) + g4(b3) + g1(b3)) / 4;
G2(b3) = (2*g0(b3) + g3(b3) + g2(b3)) / 4;
```

The first block of code generates a 2D grid of coordinates that span where you're iterating over each pixel in your image.  These generate column major indices that represent the +/- 1 offsets horizontally and vertically. The next batch of code generates 5 matrices that sample your green channel at these locations.   I also call `GreenArray` `g0` for ease of typing.

There are 3 `if` conditions within your inner most loop.  Each triplet of code after the `g0...g4` code is essentially computing each `if` statement.  We determine which locations satisfy the first `if` condition and it is stored as a mask in `b1`.  We then use this mask to index into our green channels we created and compute the correct values and place them into the right spots in `G1` and `G2`.  This is repeated for the other two `if` statements and are seen in `b2` and `b3`, which also mutate `G1` and `G2` at the right spots.

The resulting operations should mimic what you were doing in the `for` loops, but it will be a hell of a lot faster as you're vectorizing and eliminating the loops all together.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some performance increases by compiling the matlab script into an executeable, and then from labview load the executable.

http://nl.mathworks.com/products/compiler/

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/5CF9526FF069EA8E862564C400579DBA